# Is levels are there in Coded UI Testing?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am fresher to Coded UI Test Automation. I want to provide a support for 3rd party controls so i need to know about CUIT, if any levels available in CUIT please explain!!! Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate, are you asking about training, certs, best practices, implementation layers

Comment: Implementation layers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for your own controls you'll want to look at how to `Overriding` `Control.ControlAccessibleObject` on your custom controls by implementing a `ControlAccessibleObject`. Any and all properties you want to support you'll have to expose. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh552522.aspx) will explain in better detail of the specific details.

As for actual Coded UI, For Desktop controls, WPF or WinForms, you probably want to keep your `Test UI's` extra simplified Window with just your custom control so its easy to spawn.

From here, depending upon the control, you'll want to implement a matching CodedUI object. To do this, you must inherit from [UITestControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.aspx), you should inherit from the appropriate family tree like `HtmlControl`, `WinControl`, or `WpfControl`. Also you will have to override the match `PropertyNames` inner class with any extra properties you are exposing in the `ControlAccessibleObject`

If you are doing Html Development I'd highly recommend using the [Page Object Pattern](https://blogs.infosupport.com/using-codedui-testautomation-without-uimap-files/) to help give statefull changes of a webpage be more apparent based upon the return type of method calls using method chaining.

**BEWARE** if your choose to use a `UIMap` (from the builder) your `Custom Coded UI` controls will not be used in generation, most likely they'll be `HtmlCustom`, `WinCustom`, `WpfCustom`, which have very limited support. Usually I only use a `UIMap` to quickly define `Search` criteria for controls.

To note `Coded UI` uses hierarchy to help it locate the controls. So when looking for your control you should define relevant Hierarchy elements, which have a very high level of success when you define ID's for your controls

YourHtmlControl->HtmlDiv->HtmlDocument->BrowserWindow